# adminlte hide the whole sidebar on toggle

Tags: adminlte

How can I fix my left side navigation. I am using AdminLTE 2.0 from Nuget.

The error is when I toggle the side it collapse the whole side bar.But then template should partially collapse the side bar when toggled. I used the `<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-collapse sidebar-mini">`

**EDIT**

I tried downloading the template, and it works perfectly and I saw the comment before the body. `<!-- the fixed layout is not compatible with sidebar-mini -->` , so I tried to get the app.js and app.min.js and replace it in my folders, but still it does not work. Everything is collapsed on the left sidebar

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Use any of the below html:

```
1) <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-collapse sidebar-mini">

2) <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">

3) <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-collapse">
```

for me second one worked.

Comment: its worked ... my laravel also worked like this ...  laravel admin dot org ... for collapse the admin menu by default we need to set them... but what is the best way to apply this css on laravel. how can we implement it ... what is standard way to apply on laravel-admin.org?

Comment: i can found that in config/admin.php line 293... also can search your tags and find them. sidebar-collapse and others ...Supported: "fixed", "layout-boxed", "layout-top-nav", "sidebar-collapse", "sidebar-mini".